# How do I make a multi-lingual dictionary in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Are there gems available to help with this task? What are the basics I need to know to make  a multi-lingual dictionary from scratch?  What are some examples of ruby-based web-dictionaries on the web? Thanks!

Comment: For basic localization, you would use I18n http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: Here's an incomplete project that might be of interest: https://github.com/saizai/hyperdictionary . I'm a little unclear on the license; it's supposed to be open source, but it also says something about being free only for non-commercial.

Comment: @OscarDelBen is l18n also for making multi-lingual dictionaries? or is it designed for creating multiple international versions of a web application?

Comment: I found an open source dictionary project with many bilingual dictionaries in XML format.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/xdxf/files/ I am confused as to how I would start using it.  I've read up on XML but I don't know which folder to go to to find the actual XML structure.  So much to learn :/

Comment: Do I have to use XML Parsing and manipulate it with javascript? or is that not what I'm looking for?  Do I have to take the XML structure and somehow inject it into pre-existing tables and store the entire multi-lingual dictionary in the database? or is that too cumbersome?